# Error while trying to install iTunes on Windows 10

Tags: windows, installation, itunes, windows-10

I have a fresh installation of Windows 10 (x64) on my machine, and I'm trying to install iTunes on it but it keeps throwing me an error: "Error during assembly: 'Microsoft.VC80.CRT.type="win32",version="8.0.50727.6195",publicKeyToken"...",processorArchitecture="amd64". HRESULT: 0x80073715".

After throwing this error it rolls back, but it doesn't cancel the installation, it keeps installing and then throws another error "Service 'Apple Mobile Device Service' (Apple Mobile Device Service) failed to start. Verify that you have sufficient privileges to start system services." And than I have to cancel the installation and it rolls back.

Strangely, if I take a look at my programs list, I see that it managed to install "Apple Software Update", "Bonjour" and another compatibility app. I tried removing these apps and starting a fresh install, but the same thing happened over and over again. I searched for a few solutions online but couldn't find anything helpful.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Are you using the latest iTunes installer?  Are you using the [64-bit iTunes installer](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1615?locale=en_CA)?

Comment: You might need to install one of the C++ redistributables http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/i-am-trying-to-update-itunes-ipod-wont-sync/652447ba-2040-42dd-99ed-b110a821bbb4

Comment: Please try installing as administrator. Right click on the setup file and choose "run as administrator". Write back and let us know the results of doing this.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 - yes, I'm using the latest 64-bit installer.

Comment: @Geruta - I tried running it as an administrator, same error :(

Comment: @MC10 - I found that post also, but when I try installing vcredist_x64.exe I get "Error 1935. An error occurred during the installation of assembly. 'Microsoft.VC80.CRT.type [... continues as above]".

Comment: What about this, does it help? https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7151903 After installing the version it mentions, try PhilWinchester's suggestion.

Comment: @MC10 - Yes! That worked! Thanks, the other days when I was googling for the error that question wasn't added yet :) Thanks. Could you please add your suggestion as an answer so I can set it as the correct answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may need to install a [Visual C++ Redistributable Package](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/i-am-trying-to-update-itunes-ipod-wont-sync/652447ba-2040-42dd-99ed-b110a821bbb4).

If that does not work, try the solution below that was [suggested on Apple's forums](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7151903).

> Install [iTunes 12.2.1 for Windows (64-bit - for older video cards)](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1816)

Open iTunes and go to the Radio. Play a song from any category. After that try playing a song from your own music.

Comment: oops, make a small edit so I can upvote your answer, sorry.

Comment: @Moab What do you mean?

Comment: I down voted by accident and cannot up vote until there is an edit.